# lumen - handler.php does not reflect updates

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I modified render method of Exceptions/Handler.php to return my own response instead of rendering lumen's error page when any errors occur.

Here is my render method updated.

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // return parent::render($request, $e);
    return response()
                ->json([
                    'errors' => $e
                ]);
}
```

I expected it return my response when NotFoundHttpException happens, but lumen still shows its original error page...

I understand I should modify `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, but because it doesn't work as I expect, I modified `vendor/laravel/lumen/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` instead.
Here is the updated file.

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return response(['test'=> 'test']);
    // return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

It works as I expected (not showing error page but return json response).

In bootstrap/app.php, it seems correctly set to call `App\Exceptions\Handler::class`, not `laravel\lumen\app\Exceptions\Handler::class`.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
```

I've already tried reinstalling lumen and my docker environment.
And I tried to modify Handler.php just after installing lumen (that is no other modification in app), but it doesn't work.

Anyone knows my changes are not reflected??

Comment: Now I figured out what is bad for my code. In my bootstrap/app.php, I wrote `require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';`, but I changed here to `require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` and it works and my Handler.php was called!

Answer (score 0):

I set a wrong value for `bootstrap/app.php`.

I set like the below.

`require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';`

After I modified this part like following, lumen became to able to call Handler.php method.

`require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`